# How do I record sounds in Pro Tools LE 8 from Komplete 7 (specifically Absynth 5)?

Tags: pro-tools

I have Pro Tools LE 8 and I just picked up Komplete 7. After much effort I finally figured out how to add a plugin to a track. Right now I'm testing with Absynth.

Note: I have no midi controller. Just using the keyboard and mouse at this point.

So I add the absynth plugin to an audio track and Absynth pops up in pro tools. I click some keys and I can hear sounds through my head phones and I see bars bouncing around in pro tools. Awesome.

I arm the track and hit record and nothing records. I thought maybe it needed to be a different kind of track, midi or auxilary or something, but it's become apparent that I don't know how to use those.

How do I record these sounds?

**Update**: I still have no idea... I've tried to do this: http://www.ehow.com/how_4428304_use-instrument-tracks-protools.html

and a bunch of variations of that via youtube and other googling. I see output, but nothing gets recorded. Do I have to have some midi controller other than just clicking keys with the mouse? That would be lame.

Comment: hey guys i have pro tools Se can i use komplete elements on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used ProTools, so bear with me for a moment...

If you have a MIDI/Instrument track with the Instrument on it,
and you can hear the output sounds, and you want to record those sounds to audio,
you need to create an Audio track,
route the output from your instrument track to this new Audio track

(you may need to go through an AUX track in between the two, as I's said its been a while since I've worked with ProTools, so I'm a bit rusty on how it's done).

Then you can arm the audio track for recording and it should record the audio output from the Instrument track.

Now, on to the deeper issue.
It seems like you could benefit greatly from going right back to basics and learning how to use ProTools from the ground up. I don't mean this in a cruel way, we've all been there in the beginning. What I mean is that Midi tracks, Audio tracks, Aux channels and so forth are fundamental concepts in audio work.

I fear that even if a good, detailed answer is posted, without this basic knowledge you may still be in difficulty.
I recommend reading the manual, and maybe looking up some beginner tutorials on Youtube.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, I've put out a link to this question on my Twitter feed, hopefully it'll attract someone more knowledgable in the specifics of ProTools.

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't been able to get it, but you're absolutely right, I've been going back through the Pro Tools tutorial dvd that came with the setup. Just seems like I'm not finding a ton of great information. I'll figure it out eventually.